# translate stored procedure - to Linq2SQL (count, max, group, orderby)

Tags: linq-to-sql, count, group-by, inner-join, max

I've two tables (1:N)

```
CREATE TABLE master (idMaster int identity (1,1) not null,
 TheName varchar( 100) null,
 constraint pk_master primary key(idMaster) clustered)
```

and -

```
CREATE TABLE lnk (idSlave int not null,
 idMaster int not null,
 constraint pk_lnk_master_slave(idSlave) primary key clustered)
```

link between Master.idMaster and lnk.idMaster

I've a SQL query:

```
 select max (master.idMaster) as idMaster,
        master.theName,
        count (lnk.idSlave) as freq
  from lnk 
  inner join master ON lnk.idMaster = master.idMaster
  Group by master.theName
  order by freq desc, master.theName
```

I need to translate this T-SQL query to a Linq-to-SQL statement, preferably in C#

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the exact sql output of a Linq-to-SQL query, but this should do the trick:

```
var results = from slave in dataContext.lnks
                  group slave by slave.idMaster
                      into slaveByMaster
                        let count = slaveByMaster.Count()
                      orderby count
                      select new
                      {
                          slaveByMaster.Key,
                          count,
                      };
```

You would still need an other query to calculate the max(master.idMaster). Something like this:

```
            var result2 = (from master in dataContext.masters
                       select master.idMaster).Max();
```